# C++ , Vector & mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, vector

I found this code from: http://www.davenicholas.me.uk/blog/view_post/29/How-to-c-mysql-mac-osx

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>


#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{

    std::vector<std::string> tables;
    MYSQL_RES *result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL *connection, mysql;

    int state;

    connection = mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"localhost","username","password","database",0,0,0);

    if (connection == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << mysql_error(&mysql) << std::endl;

        return tables;
    }

    state = mysql_query(connection, "SHOW TABLES");
    if (state !=0)
    {
        std::cout << mysql_error(connection) << std::endl;
        return tables;
    }

    result = mysql_store_result(connection);

    std::cout << "tables: " << mysql_num_rows(result) << std::endl;
    while ( ( row=mysql_fetch_row(result)) != NULL )
    {
        tables.push_back(row[0]);
    }

    mysql_free_result(result);

    mysql_close(connection);
        return 0;
}
```

But when I build it I get the error:

```
error: cannot convert 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >' to 'int' in return
```

and

```
error: cannot convert 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >' to 'int' in return
```

Comment: `return tables;` main cannot return a `std::vector<std::string>` to its caller

Comment: Copy paste coding might work for languages like Java or PHP, but you are going to get destroyed if you try it in C++

Comment: I know, i would like any help..

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: Im trying to connect to mysql and read the database using c++

Comment: Before learning to connect to databases using C++, maybe you should learn using C++ first.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem may be that you do `return tables;` when the connect or query calls fail. This means that you return a `std::vector` from `main()`, and `main()` should return an `int`.

Comment: please give me example, or fix it... i want to pick the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Move this code into a function that returns `std::vector<std::string>`, and call that function from `main()`:

```
std::vector<std::string> get_tables()
{
    std::vector<std::string> tables;
    MYSQL_RES *result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL *connection, mysql;

    int state;

    connection = mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"localhost","username","password","database",0,0,0);

    ...

    return tables;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> tables = get_tables();
    // do something useful with `tables'
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user1104856 You need to learn the very basics of the language before you can hope to understand or use that code, sorry.

Comment: It still dosent work: IT SAYS warning: control reaches end of non-void function

Comment: @user1104856: With respect, my recommendation at this juncture would be to pick up a good C++ textbook. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: I will, but i did try to return tables, it says: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 1):

This code is supposed to be in another function I think, definitely not in main().

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `table` variable is defined as a `vector`, but it's returned as the function's return value; but the function is declared to have `int` as return value.
The best way to solve this problem is to move the parts which process `table` to another function and call that from main (and rewrite some parts of the code).

Comment: I try'd use the above code from aix, but i get : Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. Could you please fix it?

Comment: I don't really know what the problem is, but I guess there is something wrong either with file access or mysql access.